# Failing on unknown fields when parsing JSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I have class defining one field:

```java
class Dog {
    int legs;
}
```

and JSON that contains one field (`heads`) not defined in the class.

```json
{
  "legs": 5,
  "heads": 3
}
```

Now, when I try to parse this with `Gson`, no exception about undefined field is thrown.

```java
new Gson().fromJson(json, Dog.class);
```

How to I force this check?

This is opposite to similar questions like that [Strict JSON parsing with Google's Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163193/strict-json-parsing-with-googles-gson), which is about JSON not defining values for fields in class, whereas mine is about class not defining fields in JSON document.

It seems duplicate of [How to make GSON fail on unknown properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65202860/how-to-make-gson-fail-on-unknown-properties), but I cannot mark my question as a duplicate because the other one no upvoted answer...

There's also discussion on Gson GitHub: https://github.com/google/gson/issues/188